# Could a Label be modified by another method inside an extended class?

Tags: java, javafx, label, extends

I'm trying to create a Cinema booking system that allows the User to purchase tickets and snacks, and at each click refresh the label.

I've two classes:

```
public class DashboardUserController{

  public Label subtotal;
  public static Double subtotalCounter = 0.0;
  public static Double filmPrice;

  @FXML
  public void onWaterBottleClick(){
    subtotalCounter = subtotalCounter + 1.50;
    orderRecipt = orderRecipt + "Water Bottle 1.50£ \n";
    setSubtotal();
  }
  // and similar methods for each type of snack 

public void setSubtotal(){
    subtotal.setText(subtotalCounter.toString() + " £");
  }

// set the price for each click on the label

  public void addTicket() {
    System.out.println(subtotalCounter);
    subtotalCounter = subtotalCounter + filmPrice;
    setSubtotal();
  } 
}
```

And another class which extends the DashboardUserController

```
public class TheatresController extends DashboardUserController {

  @FXML
  private void onClick(MouseEvent event) {                  //method for selection/deselection of seats
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) event.getSource();
    if (imageView.getImage() == redSeat) {
      Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you want to proceed with the unbooking?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
      if (alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES) {
        imageView.setImage(imageView.getImage() == redSeat ? greenSeat : redSeat);
      }
    } else {
      Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you want to proceed with the booking?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
      if (alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES) {
        imageView.setImage(imageView.getImage() == redSeat ? greenSeat : redSeat);
        addTicket();
      }
    }
  }
```

The strange thing here is that if I click again any snack the Label display correctly the price of the selected food plus the price of the film for each seat selected.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To sum it up it is a Minimal(small amount of code) Complete(Fully runnable) Verifiable(I can put into my IDE and run without errors) Example(Recreate your problem).

Comment: Here I can clarify, by recreate your problem I mean rewrite the necessary code in a minimal fashion so that others on stack overflow can run your code in say an IDE you do not need to link your code but embed it into the post you can do this but indenting your code by 4 spaces like you have already done if you find that you cannot re-create the issue consistently then there is a bigger problem with the code that we cannot see(I don't want to debug your whole application) that being said maybe a walk through with the debugger will help you find the problem you want to recreate

Comment: Yes unfortunately ...

Comment: @Matt if I sent to you a link with the whole code can you check it ?

Comment: @Matt Thank' you. ufile.io/pt728

Comment: @Matt try now, sorry https://ufile.io/r766z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a lot wrong(Exaggeration for effect) but you are learning so I will do my best to help. Please read it all before copying and pasting into your program so you understand it

Starting off the reason you were getting a null pointer was due to the fact that you had `extend DashBoardUserController` which means that the `DashBoardUserController` that the program was initialized with was not talking to your `TheatresController` and when you tried to access it it gave you a null pointer because nothing was initialized in the extended class

So Step 1 remove the `extend DashBoardUserController`

So since that is gone we need to get a reference of `DashBoardUserController` to that class so that it can call the necessary methods we can do that on initialization of `TheatresController` like so

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resourceLocation));
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        TheatresController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDashBoardUserControllerReference(this);//We'll get here
```

Next is to make necessary methods and variables in `TheatresController`

```
private DashboardUserController dashboardUserController;//Set at top of class

public void setDashBoardUserControllerReference(DashboardUserController dashboardUserController){
    this.dashboardUserController = dashboardUserController;
}
```

Done this will fix the null pointer moving on to generify your method because there is a lot of code replication which for you is unnecessary typing

```
@FXML
public void onjosephclick() {
    //weekPickerInput();                                //You can delete from here
    //addFilmsInList();
    //filmList.setShowLocation("Joseph P");
    //System.out.println("joseph button pressed");
    //try {
    //    Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scenes/josephpane.fxml"));
    //    seatsSelection.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    //} catch (IOException e) {
    //    System.out.println(e);
    //}
    //setStuff();
    //seatsavailable.setText(Integer.toString(seatsJoseph));
    //filmPrice = filmList.searchFilm().get().getPrice();
    //System.out.println("Price:"+filmPrice);            //Down to here
    genericOnClick("Joseph P","scenes/josephpane.fxml",seatsJoseph);
    //change the strings for each call and remove the unnecessary stuff 
    //in the methods it will clean it up a lot
}

private void genericOnClick(String location, String resourceLocation, int seats) {
    weekPickerInput();
    addFilmsInList();
    filmList.setShowLocation(location);
    System.out.println("Location:"+location);
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resourceLocation));
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        TheatresController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDashBoardUserControllerReference(this);
        seatsSelection.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    setStuff();
    seatsavailable.setText(Integer.toString(seats));
    filmPrice = filmList.searchFilm().get().getPrice();
    System.out.println("Price:"+filmPrice);
}
```

Some other things learn to learn eventually are java naming conventions, dealing with code replication I saw a good amount of code that can be generified like I showed you in the above method

Good luck code on good sir. If its not working I can post the full class but I think you should try and figure it out as its good practice and I gave you all the code you need let me know if you need more help

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question click the check next to the question to "accept" the answer so that other do not think this question is still open

Comment: Okay, applying just now the changes, thank you so much man, If everything work I'll accept the question immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I read carefully all the things on which you focused my attention. Obviously I still need to practice, I was sure that I was able to call the methods just with the keyword "Extends". Now everything works fine.

Comment: No worries take it all in stride learn as you go ask for help if you don't understand